# No Sources menu item after upgrading to superset 0.38

Tags: apache-superset

I've upgraded to superset 0.38, and suddenly my admin user can't see the sources menu anymore. All he can see is Charts, Dashboards and SQL-Lab.
The user has all rights - Admin, Alpha, Beta, Gamma, SQL-Lab and Public.

Important to note that we use Google OAuth authentication based on flask, which probably impacts this somehow.

Comment: You might need to run `superset init`, to fix broken permission and create permissions for new views.

Comment: Trying. Doesn't work. 
Error: No such command "init".

Comment: That's strange, what do you get when you run `superset --help`?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on upgrading to 0.38.

Running `superset init` fixed it for us.

```
$ superset init
Syncing role definition
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing role definition
Syncing Admin perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Admin perms
Syncing Alpha perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Alpha perms
Syncing Gamma perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Gamma perms
Syncing granter perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing granter perms
Syncing sql_lab perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing sql_lab perms
Fetching a set of all perms to lookup which ones are missing
INFO:superset.security.manager:Fetching a set of all perms to lookup which ones are missing
Creating missing datasource permissions.
INFO:superset.security.manager:Creating missing datasource permissions.
Creating missing database permissions.
INFO:superset.security.manager:Creating missing database permissions.
Creating missing metrics permissions
INFO:superset.security.manager:Creating missing metrics permissions
Cleaning faulty perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Cleaning faulty perms
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using PIP install, so your UI interface has a data menu instead of source. I am also facing this problem at present, and I think there are two ways to deal with it: A.On the existing basis, NPM Run build front end, but the front end has been separated, I don't know how to build.B. Re-install superset through the source code. The official website simply provides the installation method through Docker, but I don't want to use Docker and don't know how to deal with the front-end code.The linked article on the website (https://hackernoon.com/a-better-guide-build-d-apache-superneck-source-6f2ki32n0) is also unclear,Provided by contributing. Md (https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/0.38/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup-local-environment-for-development) is also not clear, this is bad..